# updating values of an instance of a matrix class in C#

Tags: c#, matrix, operator-overloading

I am writing a program which is overloading some operators in C#, and I have a class Matrix on which these operators will be tested
now the problem is that
I am struggling to update the values of the newly created matrix which holds the results after overloading has occurred.
when I run it, the matrix returns zeros.

Where could have I gone wrong?

```
        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix _a, Matrix b)
        {
            int l = _a.Col; 
            if (l != b.Row)
                throw new ArgumentException("Illegal matrix dimensions for multiplication. _a.M must be equal b.N");
            Matrix result = new Matrix(rw, col);
            for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
                    {
                        result[i, j] += _matrix[i, k] * _matrix[k, j];
                    }
                }
            return result;
        }
```

The full code is [HERE](https://onlinegdb.com/SkRHCQkFD) maybe the problem is with how I initialized everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the values from your input matrices (_a and b). You are reading values from _matrix and storing the results from doing math on them in the result (it looks like you might be squareing _matrix).

Comment: I have changed the code to
`result[i, j] += _a[i, k] * b[k, j];`
but it's still giving zeros, I tried printing out the values of matrix _a and b, well it turns out they are zeros
i think the problem is with how I am reading matrix _a and matrix b